# Why does using temporary variables to store the result of function calls give different outcomes?

Tags: c++

So, I was making a sudoku game, where every square would point to every other square in its row, column, and 3x3 'area'. In the `sudoku` constructor, I connect the relevant squares. The row and column connections don't give me any unexpected results – there are 1296 connections to be made, and when that part is done, the printed `count` shows exactly 1296. Great!

Now when doing the same for the 3x3 areas, I encountered a problem. When using `option 2`, the `count` ends at 324, and when printing the board I get the desired result. However, when storing the results of the `get_node` function in a temporary variable (`option1`), I get 648 and the connection count for each square is in correct (16 instead of 20). This shouldn't be the case, as all the `get_node` function does is `return _board[(I * dim) + J]`. Does anyone know where such an issue may come from?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Yes, I temporarily disabled compiler warnings so the `goto` statements would compile – that's not the issue, it's just to make things more clear for people here to see :)

```
// areas
int count(0);
for (int a = 0; a < 3; ++a) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 3; ++b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
                for (int m = 0; m < 3; ++m) {
                    for (int n = 0; n < 3; ++n) {
                        if (i == m && j == n) continue;
                        
                        goto option1;
                        
                        //------------------------
                        
                        option1:
                        
                        {
                        auto current_node = get_node(a*3 + i, b*3 + j);
                        auto potential_connection = get_node(a*3 + m, b*3 + n);
                        
                        if (ISINSIDE(current_node.get_connections(), &potential_connection)) continue;
                        current_node.add_connection(&potential_connection);
                        
                        goto end;
                        }
                        
                        //------------------------
                        
                        option2:
                        {
                        
                        if (ISINSIDE(get_node(a*3 + i, b*3 + j).get_connections(), &get_node(a*3 + m, b*3 + n))) continue;
                        get_node(a*3 + i, b*3 + j).add_connection(&get_node(a*3 + m, b*3 + n));
                        
                        goto end;
                        }
                                                    
                        //------------------------
                        
                        end:
                        count += 1;
                        std::cout << count << '\n';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no `goto option2` in your posted code, and the given flow basically means that you could literally remove every `goto` and label in your code and it would function the same. Why use `goto`? Hiding the errors/warnings very well _could_ be part of your issue here, especially if they're unresolved. All that said, a >3-dimensional loop for a 3-dimensional construct is a bit of a smell.

Comment: Show `get_node()` please.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I did – I said that "all the get_node function does is `return _board[(I * dim) + J]`."

Comment: @JoligeJ apologies, sometimes I gloss over text (very often noise on this site, you wouldn't believe it!) in favor of reading the code. I may not be the only one with a kneejerk reaction to a `goto` online though. Code comments are great!

Comment: **Don't write code like this.**

Comment: @JoligeJ *that's not the issue, it's just to make things more clear for people here to see* -- As soon as you used `goto` in your code, you've turned away many posters from trying to solve your problem.  The reason is that very few will want to try to untangle code that is not structured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The codes are different.

`&get_node(a*3 + m, b*3 + n)` is `&_board[idx]`, the address of some array element.

`&potential_connection` is not an address of the array element, this is a completely different address, the address of the local variable `auto potential_connection = ...`

That should fix the issue

```
auto& potential_connection = get_node(a*3 + m, b*3 + n);
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow, the issue didn't resolve itself when making `potential_connection` a reference variable, but it did when doing so to `current_node`... The issue apparently lay with the latter variable – could you perhaps explain why that might've been the case?

Comment: @JoligeJ probably not without a [mre]

Comment: @JoligeJ You are most likely copying an object and modifying the copy. I think the real question you need to ask is whether you understand the difference between `auto a=f();` and `auto& a=f();`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, Yes, in fact I do. It simply was to do with the `count` variable :)